# How to convert slope handling code to work with AddForce instead of AddRelativeForce?

Tags: unity, rigidbody

I an using the following code for handling slopes:

```
      private Vector3 PlayerSlope()
      {
          Vector3 calculatedPlayerMovement = _playerMoveInput;

          if (_playerIsGrounded)
          {
              Vector3 localGroundCheckHitNormal = _rigidbody.transform.InverseTransformDirection(_groundCheckHit.normal);

              float groundSlopeAngle = Vector3.Angle(localGroundCheckHitNormal, _rigidbody.transform.up);
              if (groundSlopeAngle == 0.0f)
              {
                  //if (_input.MoveIsPressed)
                  if (moveDirectionRaw != Vector3.zero && moveDirection != Vector3.zero)
                  {
                      RaycastHit rayHit;
                      float rayCalculatedRayHeight = _playerCenterPoint.y - _playerCenterToGroundDistance + _groundCheckDistanceTolerance;
                      Vector3 rayOrigin = new Vector3(_playerCenterPoint.x, rayCalculatedRayHeight, _playerCenterPoint.z);
                      if (Physics.Raycast(rayOrigin, _rigidbody.transform.TransformDirection(calculatedPlayerMovement), out rayHit, 0.75f))
                      {
                          if (Vector3.Angle(rayHit.normal, _rigidbody.transform.up) > _maxSlopeAngle)
                          {
                              Debug.Log(_playerMoveInput.y);
                              calculatedPlayerMovement.y = -_movementMultiplier;
                          }
                      }
                      //Debug.DrawRay(rayOrigin, _rigidbody.transform.TransformDirection(calculatedPlayerMovement), Color.green, 1.0f);
                  }

                  if (calculatedPlayerMovement.y == 0.0f)
                  {
                      calculatedPlayerMovement.y = _gravityGrounded;
                  }
              }
              else
              {
                  Quaternion slopeAngleRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(_rigidbody.transform.up, localGroundCheckHitNormal);
                  calculatedPlayerMovement = slopeAngleRotation * calculatedPlayerMovement;

                  float relativeSlopeAngle = Vector3.Angle(calculatedPlayerMovement, _rigidbody.transform.up) - 90.0f;
                  calculatedPlayerMovement += calculatedPlayerMovement * (relativeSlopeAngle / 90.0f);

                  if (groundSlopeAngle < _maxSlopeAngle)
                  {
                      //if (_input.MoveIsPressed)
                      if (moveDirectionRaw != Vector3.zero && moveDirection != Vector3.zero)
                      {
                          calculatedPlayerMovement.y += _gravityGrounded;
                      }
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      float calculatedSlopeGravity = groundSlopeAngle * -0.2f;
                      if (calculatedSlopeGravity < calculatedPlayerMovement.y)
                      {
                          calculatedPlayerMovement.y = calculatedSlopeGravity;
                      }
                  }
              }
              //#if UNITY_EDITOR
              //            Debug.DrawRay(_rigidbody.position, _rigidbody.transform.TransformDirection(calculatedPlayerMovement), Color.red, 0.5f);
              //#endif
          }

          return calculatedPlayerMovement;
      }
```

And then, in the FixedUpdate, it is applied as so:

```
    _playerMoveInput = PlayerMove(); //horizontal and vertical direction input multiplied by speed is returned from playermove
    _playerMoveInput = PlayerSlope();
    _rigidbody.AddRelativeForce(_playerMoveInput, ForceMode.Force);
```

My question is, how can I make the slope handling code work if instead I use AddForce in FixedUpdate? Like so: `_rigidbody.AddForce(_playerMoveInput, ForceMode.Force);`

If I just simply change `AddRelativeForce` to `AddForce` there, then the slope logic breaks and my rigidbody starts skipping down slopes again. So I know I should be changing code in `PlayerSlope()`, but I'm not sure what to change to make it work as an AddForce instead of AddRelativeForce.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AddRelativeForce` is basically just syntactic sugar over `AddForce`, transforming the force from local to world coordinates for you so you don't have to do that step explicitly. We could implement it like an extension method:

```cs
public static AddRelativeForce(this Rigidbody body, 
                            Vector3 localForce, 
                          ForceMode mode = ForceMode.Force) {

    var worldForce = body.transform.TransformVector(localForce);
    body.AddForce(worldForce, mode);
}
```

Comment: Wow! Awesome. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The difference between AddForce and AddRelativeForce is simple but critical to understand.

AddRelativeForce simply adds a force in a specified direction that's relative to the affected rigidbody's transform whereas AddForce uses world space.

One can use AddForce with this script pretty simply by first just converting the calculated input/force before calling AddForce.

`_rigidbody.AddForce(transform.TransformDirection(_playerMoveInput), ForceMode.Force);`